# How to get parameter types of a generic function with instantiated generic type parameters?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

My goal is to extract the `Parameter` types of a generic typed function into a new generic type which I can use later:

```js
// we have a given function like this:
function genericFunction<T>(a: T) {
  return a;
}

type genericParamsType = Parameters<typeof genericFunction>; // this will resolve to a type of [unknown]
// I would like to achieve something like this:
// type genericParamsType<PassDownType> = Parameters<typeof genericFunction<PassDownType>>;
// but that is a syntax error

// if it would work, I could the following:
// const newparams: genericParamsType<string> = ["hello"] // correct
// const newparams2: genericParamsType<number> = ["hello"] // error because its not a string
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1PaXW)

Comment: How flexible your solution needs to be? This specific function only? Any function with one generic argument? Any number of generic arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 4.7 introduced [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions), so your original idea is no longer a syntax error. Instantiation expressions allow generic functions to be, well, instantiated with concrete types for generic type parameters.

Thus, `genericParamsType` can be written as follows:

```js
type genericParamsType<T> = Parameters<typeof genericFunction<T>>;
```

While this still does not allow for a truly general solution as one still has to use the `typeof` type query on a concrete implementation, it is sufficient to cover the use case outlined in the question:

```js
// we have a given function like this:
function genericFunction<T>(a: T) {
  return a;
}

type genericParamsType<T> = Parameters<typeof genericFunction<T>>;

const newparams: genericParamsType<string> = ["hello"] // OK
const newparams2: genericParamsType<number> = ["hello"] // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdAa0m)

Comment: Awesome! And even exactly the syntax I used before it existed. Very intuitive 

Comment: Yea, @josias - when they first announced instantiation expressions, I was a bit sceptical as to what real use-cases for it could be, but since it allows for use cases like yours, it started to grow on me. I wish it could work in the general case of a generic function signature without implementation, but heck, maybe it'll happen in future versions of TS